# Devise deletes credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i implemented a friendship model using rails 3.. now i want to enable the users to add new friends...from the looks of it, i guess i need 2 for loops...one for looping all the users and another one for checking if that user is already a friend....  but if i use 2 for loops, i don't get the result that i am expecting and the email of the users who are alraedy the friends of current user prints and the address gets printed multiple times (because of the 2nd for loop as i am printing it inside the loop) .. is there any other way to get around this issue????

```
code:
this is my view file:

<center>Bragger's list<center><br/>
<p>
  <% for user in User.all %>
    <% if current_user.email!= user.email %>
      <% for friend in current_user.friends %>
        <% if friend.email!=user.email %>
          <p>
            <%= user.email %> &nbsp; <%= link_to 'Add as Friend' , friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>
          </p>
          <br/> 
        <%end%>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to this is to filter the list of users in your controller that is not yet a friend of the current_user.  You can do that by

```
@potential_friends = User.where('id != ? AND id NOT IN (?)', current_user.id, current_user.friend_ids)
```

Then just loop over this variable in the view

```
<center>Bragger's list<center><br/>
<p>
  <% @potential_friends.each do |user| %>
    <p>
      <%= user.email %> &nbsp; <%= link_to 'Add as Friend' , friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>
    </p>
    <br/> 
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something else,

`User.where('user_id not in (?)', current_user.friends.map(&:id).push(current_user.id))`

This would get all the users from the database that are not your current_user's friends and then you have only to loop once.